# gtest capture result of EXPECT_NO_THROW statement

Tags: c++, googletest

Say I have a method which creates a non-trivially constructable object which is RVO'd back to the caller. For example

```
MyComplexClass value = deserialize();
```

`deserialize` throws an exception on failure, so I want to do something like

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW(MyComplexClass value = deserialize());
```

but of course, value goes out of scope (since the macro introduces a try/catch block).
And also

```
MyComplexClass value;
EXPECT_NO_THROW(value = deserialize());
```

does not work since there is no default constructor (for example it is `= delete`).

Any ideas on this? I could do something like

```
template<typename TResult>
TResult return_assert_no_throw(std::function<TResult()> expression)
{
    try
    {
        return expression();
    }
    catch (const std::exception & ex)
    {
        ASSERT_TRUE(false);
    }
}
```

but this seems a little hacky, and we lose information on the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the desired syntax of `value = deserialize()` more generally, whatever type value is it should be copy-able and/or move-able for that to work. Therefore if you can create a dummy value/null valued instance of the class you are still good to go. You can simply initialise `value` to a particular dummy/canary instance, and then verify afterwards that the value changed properly. You may have/want to `std::swap()`.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is movable and can have a null value. But I do not get it to work. Can you add a code example to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to having a dummy instance is using emplace in a collection:

```
std::vector<MyComplexClass> v;
EXPECT_NO_THROW(v.emplace_back(deserialize()));
// work with v[0] as the value
```

Comment: to that end, we could even use `std::optional`

Answer (score 1):

You could just dispense with `EXPECT_NO_THROW`. Gtest will fail the test if an uncaught exception escapes from the test body.